# Type casting from Int to double in c# eror

Tags: c#

I am trying to type cast an int value into double to compute average precisely but I am getting this error.

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>       Error   CS1525  Invalid expression term 'double'

I have'nt used c# for a while so it's possible I am wrong syntax wise. But looking around the web I found no answer.

Here's the code the won`t compile.

```
static int AvgDigits(int n)
{        
    return  SumDigits(n) / double(Dignum(n));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enclose **`double`** into paranthesis `((double)(Dignum(n)))` which will cast the value **`Dignum(n)`** into dobule

```
return  SumDigits(n) / ((double)(Dignum(n)));
```

also since you are casting it to double, your return type should be double,

```
static double AvgDigits(int n)
{        
   return  SumDigits(n) / ((double)(Dignum(n)));
}
```

Comment: That was one of the problems. I also forgot to change the function return type from int to double. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Up to my knowledge, the function should be named static double blablabla. You see, when you return something, it has to be a type compatible with the output value of the function. If not, JRE will let you know that the desire to truncate the, in this case, double to int should be explicitly menioned.

In 
static int AvgDigits(int n)
It receives an int and returns an int. Seeing as the operation is in fact a double, you could try changing the function to
static double AvgDigits(int n)

Good luck! Tell me if it worked!